Is it a cheating if I used a formula I found online in homework without citing the course (math class)?
A student used a formula in math homework that they found online. They didn't cite the source.
The formula wasn't covered in the class and the method is different from what was covered in the class. The student didn't provide the derivation of the formula and couldn't explain why the formula is valid. They admitted they found it online.
Is this considered cheating? This is in the US undergraduate institution. The syllabus says "You are not allowed to search for specific homework questions parts online".
I believe the situation is not the same as in Is it fair to use techniques I found on the web to solve my assignment?
because the student doesn't understand where the formulas came from.

Rules and expectations differ. It is a local question.

I edited the post. I believe the situation is different.

The title says "Is it a cheating if I used a formula", the body refers to "A student". While I understand some interest in ambiguity to try to answer a general question, I don't think it's an usefully answerable one. What is and is not cheating is very dependent on context. In many cases its up to the instructor to determine. Are you an instructor looking for help on how to decide what is and isn't cheating in your class? Are you a student trying to interpret your instructor's guidelines? If so, why not ask your instructor?

Also possibly relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Researching different method rather than regurgitating lecture method: +15 marks. Not being able to explain: -5 marks. Not knowing why it works: -5 marks. Not citing the method: if it is considered general knowledge - no cheating; if it is a method specialized to the problem at hand - cheating. There, enjoy the flow diagram...
